# Realtime Single Object Tracking with TensorFlow.js

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm putting my first steps in Machine Learning, I went through many TensorFlow.js tutorials already and I'm trying to achieve this: "Realtime Single Object Tracking/Detection"

Something like this -> input: webcam/video -> output: object bounding box

I know there are SSD and YOLO, and other libraries to predict & locate the objects. But the predicted time is very slow (in browser), I guessed it's because the Neural Network have to predict between so many objects.

https://github.com/ModelDepot/tfjs-yolo-tiny
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection

What if I just want to track a single object? Would it be possible? Will the performance be better? Where should I start?

I've been thinking about extract the pre-trained class (object) from a SavedModel, then start training more from it. But there don't seems to be any instructions around Google.

Answer (score 4):

I found some fantastic code by IBM, which I used in the video in this tweet:  https://twitter.com/GantLaborde/status/1125735283343921152?s=20

I extracted that code to make a ReactJS component for detecting Rock/Paper/Scissors here: https://github.com/GantMan/rps_tfjs_demo/blob/master/src/AdvancedModel.js

If you'd like to play with the demo, it's at the bottom of this page: https://rps-tfjs.netlify.com/

All of this is open source and seems to work perfectly fast for detecting a single object in realtime.[image]

Comment: works pretty well on my iPhone 7 Plus in Safari.  Not so much in Chrome on iOS.   As with all things mobile web, it's slower and depends.